# Can HERE map services run on Epson Moverio BT-200 (Android 4.0.4 API 15)?

Tags: android, here-api

I have been testing out the HERE Android premium SDK (Specifically the mapping classes and MapOffscreenRenderer) on Google Glass (KitKat 4.4.4, API level 19), and it has been working beautifully.

I encountered problems, however, when running the same application on a pair of Moverio BT-200s (ICS 4.0.4, API level 15). The API documentation indicates that this version should be supported, but when I run the app it fails to download any tiles. Is this an issue with android 4.0.4 support, or do I just need to initialize the service differently? (Relevant Logcat snippets below)

**Initial Error:**

```
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.here.network.NetworkProtocol.send(NetworkProtocol.java:471)
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:607)
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:607)
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:190)
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:
... 2 more
```

**Later, every download fails with:**

```
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 I/dalvikvm: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class Lcom/here/network/NetworkProtocol$GetTask; v=0x0 09-06 14:36:43.263 3942-3991/global.Here.Map.Service.v2 E/NETWORKANDROID: Failed to call Send
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/here/network/NetworkProtocol$GetTask
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at com.here.network.NetworkProtocol.send(NetworkProtocol.java:471)
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
global.Here.Map.Service.v2 E/NETWORK: Request: https://version.hybrid.api.here.com/ver/v1/15.1.0.0/maps.xml?prd=B81400416E64726F6964205072656D69756D2053444B00B90600342E302E3400BA13004550534F4E20656D6274323B20656E5F555300BB2C006E447264555833465353454A594B3156456C6D3161773A543958506A4A506932696756326679636C4F584100BC0400312E3000E21500543958506A4A506932696756326679636C4F584100E317006E447264555833465353454A594B3156456C6D31617700E50A00332E322E312E34333900 Error: -1 I/O Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the AOSP runtime does not like one particular line of code in our networking layer. I will log a bug and have this address.

Sorry, until we fix the bug it will not work for your application :(

Comment: Thank you for the swift response! After some more digging through the traces I'm fairly sure that the root cause is described [here](http://experiments-on-android.blogspot.com/2014/03/start-asynctask-from-thread-before-api.html). 

In short: as of Jellybean calling ExecuteOnExecutor will work from any thread, but on ICS you have to stick the call in a runnable and pass it off to a looper retrieved from the application context when creating your GetTask, Otherwise you'll see this crash.